# Convert Future[Object] to another Future[Object] containing a list

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a method that calls a third-party endpoint to return a list of provider objects of Future type. Now I want to call this method and convert that object to a different future object containing the list. Here are the models:

```scala
case class ThirdPartyProvidersResponse(providers: List[ThirdPartyProvider])

case class ThirdPartyProvider(
    id: String,
    config: List[Config]
)

// Convert ThirdPartyProvidersResponse to DomainProvidersResponse

case class DomainProvidersResponse(
    providers: List[DomainProviderResponse]
)

case class DomainProviderResponse(
    code: Option[DomainProviderType],
    enabled: Boolean
)
```

This is the method signature that I am attempting to implement:

```
def getProviders(): Future[DomainProvidersResponse]
```

This is the definition of the API method:

```
def getProvidersList(): Future[ThirdPartyProvidersResponse]
```

This is what I have tried:

```
def getProviders(): Future[DomainProvidersResponse] = {
  var providers: List[DomainProviderResponse] = List()
  thirdPartyServiceHttpClient.getProvidersList().map { response =>
    response.providers.map { providersList =>
      val provider = DomainProviderResponse(
        providerCode = DomainProviderType.findByName(providersList.id),
        enabled = true
      )
      providers :+= provider
    }
  }
  Future.successful(DomainProvidersResponse(providers = providers))
}
```

The problem with this code is synchronization. I need to wait for the future to execute before the result can be returned. Can we achieve this using `flatMap` by performing the conversion at once without having to explicitly synchronize?

Any help on this is appreciated. I come from a Java background and am new to Scala.

Comment: Is `getProvidersList()` a `Future[Response]`  or `List[Response]`? Is `response.providers` a `List[sth]` or `Future[sth]`?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok It is a `Future[ThirdPartyProvidersResponse]`.

Comment: And what about `response.providers`? You are using `map` with `map` to obtain `    `providersList`.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok `response.providers` is a List. Please check the models in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need something like `map` or for-comprehension:

```
def getProviders(): Future[DomainProvidersResponse] =
  for {
    response <- thirdPartyServiceHttpClient.getProvidersList()
    domainProviders = response.providers.map { provider =>
     DomainProviderResponse(
        providerCode = DomainProviderType.findByName(providersList.id),
        enabled = true
      )
    }
  } yield DomainProvidersResponse(domainList)
// or
def getProviders(): Future[DomainProvidersResponse] =
  thirdPartyServiceHttpClient.getProvidersList().map { response =>
   response.providers.map { provider =>
     DomainProviderResponse(
        providerCode = DomainProviderType.findByName(providersList.id),
        enabled = true
      )
    }
  }.map { domainProviders =>
    DomainProvidersResponse(domainList)
  }
```